# How to get a snapshot of Custom sections in standard or custom vf page?

Tags: visualforce

i created two custom sections and make it as inline in Account detail page. And for each section i embeded visualforce page that would displays tabular data from a webservice call.

Now i want that two custom sections (i.e., the sections not having any custom object, but inline vf page) to be displayed as a snapshot on the top as given in the below screenshot so that user can easily access the section without scrolling all the way down to view the details. Is that possible? Please suggest? Experts please advise...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is not possible.

That list is called `relatedListHover` and you only can set enabled or disabled on it.

I believe that could be possible to make a component using some magical javascript to replicate that standard feature.